# How do victims of extended coma survive in the World of Fire and Ice?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

I don't know what the book details are, but in the TV show

> Bran Stark

survives a coma that is implied to have lasted longer than a month.  Since there seem to be no feeding tubes or intravenous injections in the World of Fire and Ice, this is slightly fantastical.  Do the books go into detail about his treatment during his coma (magical/ritual treatments, or rectal feeding/hyrdration maybe), or is his survival simple anachronism?

Comment: They use Athelas, Kingsfoil. No, wait...

Comment: “*This is slightly fantastical*” well the show is a fantasy series, so you’ve got that part right!

Comment: https://academic.oup.com/brain/article/131/3/877/317052 - Probably the same way that real-world medieval people survived comas. Those with no swallow response tended to die, those in more shallow comas tended to survive

Comment: _"This is slightly fantastical"_ but it's okay that he goes on to remotely transmit his consciousness into birds, wolves and people

Comment: I didn't mean the fantastical was out of bounds, I just meant it warrants some explanation.  And TheLethalCarrot's answer shows that warging magic is indicated to explain his survival and recovering, so, super.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

They fed him honey and water, it is probably just enough to survive though Bran would have lost a lot of weight.

> "Will Bran get better, Uncle?" little Myrcella asked. She had all of her mother's beauty, and none of her nature.
>   "His back is broken, little one," Tyrion told her. "The fall shattered his legs as well. **They keep him alive with honey and water**, or he would starve to death. Perhaps, if he wakes, he will be able to eat real food, but he will never walk again."
>   <sub>A Game of Thrones, Tyrion I</sub>

It’s worth noting though that his connection to Summer seems to have helped his recovery.

> "The gods alone know," Tyrion told her. "The maester only hopes." He chewed some more bread. "**I would swear that wolf of his is keeping the boy alive.** The creature is outside his window day and night, howling. Every time they chase it away, it returns. **The maester said they closed the window once, to shut out the noise, and Bran seemed to weaken.** When they opened it again, his heart beat stronger."
>   <sub>ibid</sub>